# Authentication Failure when connecting to sharepoint using sharepy

Tags: python

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
import sharepy
from sharepy import connect
from sharepy import SharePointSession 
    
server="https://company.sharepoint.com"
user="user@company.com" // username
password="passcode" //passcode
    
s = sharepy.connect(server,user,password)
```

and here is the error I‘m getting:

> *error : Authentication Failure: AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password*

Comment: Is it a  SharePoint Online/O365 site ?

Comment: i tried opening it like
login in to office365 > click sharepoint

Comment: did you tried it from the command line using just sharepy.connect("your server url here")?

Comment: sharepoint online @GuillaumeRAYMOND

Comment: not tried ......

Comment: i tried using command line same error was showing

Comment: I saw 2 open issues on github I guess 1 is your. I'm afraid you have to dig it by yourself: You can fork the project and try to fix it or contact the author if not already done via his website https://rocketchilli.com/. You can also make use of SoapUI to test if [this approach] (https://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/) still work

Comment: thanks , but do you have any idea about the issue im facing

Comment: Not really I guess the way to authenticate is outdated maybe this [REST API approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/sharepoint-rest-graph) is more up to date.

Comment: thanks fro your soapui website sir, i copied the cookies rtf and fedauth and passed in header now i got 200 and able to download files ......

Answer (score 1):

It‘s a library version error.
Please uninstall and reinstall sharepy like this :

```
pip uninstall sharepy

pip install sharepy==2.0.0b1.post2
```